# Delete sublists of list with given properties

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form `list={list1,list2,...}`, where `list1` is of the form `{a,b,c,d}` and similarly for other sublists, i.e. `list2`,`list3` etc.

I would like to select the sublists of the `list` that have $a\neq b$ **and** $c\neq d$. I tried to use `DeleteCases`, but I am not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: `Select` will be more natural here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "d"], {10, 4}]
```

> {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"c", "c", "c", "c"}, {"a", "a", "a", "c"},
>         {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c", "a"}, {"a", "d", "c",  "b"},
>         {"c", "a", "d", "d"}, {"c", "c", "b", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d",  "a"}, {"d", "a", "c", "c"}}

```
DeleteCases[data, {a_, a_, _, _} | {_, _, b_, b_}]
```

> {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c", "a"}, 
>      {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}

```
Select[data, UnsameQ @@ #[[;; 2]] && UnsameQ @@ #[[3 ;;]] &]
```

> {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c", "a"}, 
>      {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
Delete[data, Position[
    Differences[ArrayReshape[data, {Length[data], 2, 2}], {0, 1}],
    {{0, 0}}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"c", "c", "c", "c"}, {"a", "a", "a", "c"}, 
   {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c", "a"}, {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, 
   {"c", "a", "d", "d"}, {"c", "c", "b", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}, 
   {"d", "a", "c", "c"}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {{a_, a_, __} | {__, a_, a_} ..}]
```

{{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c",
"a"}, {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceList` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
patt = {Repeated[a_, {2}], __} | {__, Repeated[a_, {2}]};

list /. Thread[Union@ReplaceList[list, {__, s : patt, ___} :> s] -> Nothing]
```

> {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c",
> "a"}, {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_, c_, d_} /; a =!= b && c =!= d]
```

> {{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c",
> "a"}, {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "d"], {10, 4}];
```

```
Pick[#,MapThread[DiscreteDelta,MapApply[KroneckerDelta]/@{#[[All,;;2]],
    #[[All,3;;]]}],1]&[data]

(* {{b,d,b,a},{b,c,b,d},{c,b,c,a},{a,d,c,b},{a,c,d,a}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "d"], {10, 4}]
```

**Using `Pick`, `UnsameQ` and `Partition`:**

```
Pick[data, And @@ UnsameQ @@@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ data]
```

---

**Using `SequenceCases`:**

```
SequenceCases[data, {k : {a_, Except[a_], b_, Except[b_]} ..} :> k]
```

**Using `Subtract`:**

```
{#1 - #2, #3 - #4} & @@@ data // Map[Apply[Times]] // 
  Position[#, Except[0], 1, Heads -> False] & // Extract[data, #] &
```

---

For readability:

```
Second = #[[2]] &;
Third = #[[3]] &;
Fourth = #[[4]] &;
IsNotTheSameAs = UnsameQ;
f = (First@#~IsNotTheSameAs~Second@#)~
    And~(Third@#~IsNotTheSameAs~Fourth@#) &;

Pick[data, f /@ data]
```

or

```
Select[f][data]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[_?(Not@*f)][data]
```

---

*Result:*

```
{{"b", "d", "b", "a"}, {"b", "c", "b", "d"}, {"c", "b", "c", 
  "a"}, {"a", "d", "c", "b"}, {"a", "c", "d", "a"}}
```